# Term for invokation of an action from an agreement

Tags: word-request

In legal terms, we can have an agreement that specifies price, SLA etc. Then, as the agreement is effective, nothing happens, because the specified conditions declare what's going to be performed once one of the parties makes a request. One can say that the parties agree how to do something **when or if** a need appears.

I need a word for such an invocation of e.g. stuff hire or purchase, according to the conditions from the agreements.

An example would be hiring consultants. In exchange for exclusivity with hires, they promise to deliver a dude or dudess within X days for Y monetary units. Then, a few months later, I say - let's go, get me a dude or dudess. What is the name of the act of me doing that with the agreement?

Comment: You could say you're asking them to [**fulfill**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fulfill) the terms of the contract.

Comment: @CanadianYankee If expressed as a noun, would you say *a contract fullfillment request* then? It sounds as the contract is entirely delivered, in my ears. I'm referring to an act where the contract in activated, results in one of unknown number of deliverables and remains passively effective until the next request, if such ever takes place.

Comment: You're right that it could sound like it's the delivery of the entire contract - you'd have to qualify it with more words: "I'm requesting the extra labor promised by the fulfillment of paragraph 4," for example.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Good point. I was hoping for something fairly brief and square, though. How would you feel if you, given the requirements above, saw *a call-off*? Would it make sense or is totally unhelpful?

Comment: No, a call-off is a particular type of contract, not the fulfillment of a part of a contract.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Ah, I'm starting to get it. So we could invoke a contract of type *call-off*, right? Would you say that *a call-off invocation* sounds acceptable from grammatical point of view?

Answer (score 1):

I might use “[exercise](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/exercise)”, or *To put into action, practice, or force; to make use of something, such as a right or option.*

> I am exercising the option in my contract and taking a three month sabbatical.

Used as a noun, it is still just "exercise", as in this example from [acquisition.gov](https://www.acquisition.gov/far/17.207):

> The contract modification or other written document which notifies the contractor **of the exercise of the option** shall cite the option clause as authority.

Note that this is very formal legal language. I think that you might also see "executed" in the context of a contract, but that means something different; It means that the contract has been signed and is binding, not that you are invoking some portion of your rights under that contract.

Comment: What would be an appropriate noun describing such an action? Would you say that *a contract exercision* is acceptable? Or perhaps is *a contract invocation* to be preferred?